# Looping with different command line arguments from Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, gcc

The C program file (on `Desktop`) which I'm trying to execute from the **Ubuntu terminal** is named `distribution.c`.

I'm currently executing it using:

```
<admin-name>@<admin-name>-Latitude-E4310:~/Desktop$ g++ -o test distribution.c
<admin-name>@<admin-name>-Latitude-E4310:./test d0=0.3 d1=0.7 >output.txt
```

This is fine for writing the output generated by the .c program file to a .txt file, named `output.txt`. However, my aim is to generate the output files for each value of `d0` ranging from `0.0` to `1.0` (in steps of `0.01`). One constraint is that `d1=1-d0`. The output files should be named like `ouputxyz.txt` where `xyz` corresponds to the three digits in the value of `d0`. (Example: Output file name is `output010.txt` when `d0=0.10`). Is it possible to write a **loop** for this task, from the Ubuntu terminal itself? (I do not want to add another loop in the original program for this.)

By the way, please let me know in the comments if you need any other detail about what I'm trying to do or you think the question can be improved and/or made more specific. I'll be happy to elaborate.

Comment: No reason for the C tag as it doesn't matter how the `test`program was created. Just search for "bash for loop" and you'll find many simple to use examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic - so you have to resort to something like `bc` - as in the example below.

The easiest thing to do would be to place this in a Bash script. (You will need `bc` installed.)

```
for ((i=0; i<=100; i++))
do
    x=`echo "scale=2; $i/100" | bc`
    y=`echo "scale=2; 1-$x" | bc`
    d0=`printf %.2f $x`
    d1=`printf %.2f $y`
    filename=`printf output%03d.txt $i`
    ./test d0=$d0 d1=$d1 >$filename
done
```

Comment: If I want to change it to `for ((i=0; i<=100; i++))`, how should I change the value of `scale`? Essentially I need `d0` to run through all the values from `0.0` to `1.0` in steps of `0.01`.

Comment: @Blue: you will need to set `scale=2`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the case above, but one addition is that another parameter `p` also varies from from `0.00` to `1.00` in steps of `0.01`.

```
for ((n=0; n<=100; n++))
do
x=`echo "scale=2; $n/100" | bc`
y=`echo "scale=2; 1-$x" | bc`
    for ((i=0; i<=100; i++))
    do
        z=`echo "scale=2; $i/100" | bc`
        d0=`printf %.2f $x`
        d1=`printf %.2f $y`
        p=`printf %.2f $z`
        filename=`printf output%03d.txt $n`
        ./test L=1000 n=100 d0=$d0 d1=$d1 p=$p >>$filename
    done
done
```